# how to separate the content of a string?

Tags: android, json, google-maps

json gives me a value which contains three values ​​within which I keep in separate

map gives me a content, that content has 3 values ​​should be separated, that language occupies?

```
 "mapa":[
    "a:3:{s:7:\"address\";s:54:\"Volc\u00e1n Parinacota 1202-1220, Chill\u00e1n, Biob\u00edo, Chile\";
     s:3:\"lat\";s:19:\"-36.620445433045944\";
     s:3:\"lng\";s:18:\"-72.07966608584445\";
         }"
        ]
```

Comment: apologies, paste the text in Spanish, but still is not to give negative

Comment: I just need to separate content delivery map, save when these were stored as 1 single variable, but with coordinates or positions that are not language or method used to separate and save

Answer (score 1):

In a JSON string , there are two symbols that guide you through parsing :

{ - indicates a JSONObject

[ - indicates a JSONArray

When parsing a json string, you should go through this items iteratively. To understand how many JsonObjects and JsonArrays you have in your string , and from which you should start parsing, use a json-visualizer tool like [this website](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/). :
[image]

**Example :** As you see, the root object is a JSONObject which consists of an JSONArray with three jsonOnjects. To parse such a structure you can use :

```
JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(jsonstring);

String result = jsonObject.getString("success");
String error_number = jsonObject.getString("error_number");    
String error_message = jsonObject.getString("error_message"); 

JSON Array jsonarray = jsonobj.getJSONArray();

String[] names = new String[jsonArray.length()];    
String[] formattedNames = new String[jsonArray.length()];  

for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    names [i] = jsonObject.getString("name");
    formattedNames [i] = jsonObject.getString("formattedName");
  }
```

Comment: understand but what about `"mapa"`, the value it brings is different inside, like separated?

Comment: actually, the json that you've pasted is invalid. Paste the correct one. I assume that mapa should be a jsonobject which consists different json arrays with again jsonobjects inside them

Comment: process the json I can do, so I have no problems when ero map process, the content delivers me as only a value, but are saved in 3 values​​, I want to separate these values